# Pure functional graph connectivity

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand functional programming better and decided to implement some classic graph algorithms. I've implemented connectivity by wrapping BFS loop into tail-recursive function but this code doesn't look much better than imperative. Is there a way to implement it better (using `for` comprehensions, monads, whatever)?

```
object Graph {
  def apply(n: Int) = new Graph(n, Vector.fill(n)(List.empty[Int]))
}

class Graph private (val n: Int, val adj: IndexedSeq[List[Int]])  {
  def addEdge(u: Int, v: Int) = {
    new Graph(n, adj.updated(u, v :: adj(u)).updated(v, u :: adj(v)))
  }


  def connected = {
    @tailrec
    def connectedIter(q: Queue[Int], visited: Seq[Boolean]) : Boolean = {
      if(q.isEmpty) visited.forall(x => x) else {
        val (v, newq) = q.dequeue
        val newVisited = visited.updated(v, true)
        connectedIter(adj(v).foldLeft(newq){(acc, x) => if(visited(x)) acc else acc.enqueue(x)}, newVisited)
      }
    }

    connectedIter(Queue[Int](0), IndexedSeq.fill(n)(false))
  }
}
```

P.S. It looks a bit better with inherently recursive DFS

```
  def reachableDfs(v: Int): Seq[Boolean] = reachableDfs(v, Vector.fill(n)(false))

  private def reachableDfs(v: Int, visited: Seq[Boolean]) : Seq[Boolean] = {
    val newV = visited.updated(v, true)
    adj(v).filterNot{x => newV(x)}.foldLeft(newV){(acc, x) => reachableDfs(x, acc)}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try an alternative and more functional approach to the Graph datatype:

Martin Erwig. 2001. Inductive graphs and functional graph algorithms. J. Funct. Program. 11, 5 (September 2001), 467-492. DOI=10.1017/S0956796801004075

Answer (score 1):

You could express this with `Set`operations, although this might be less efficient:

```
object Graph {
  def apply(n: Int) = new Graph(n, Vector.fill(n)(Set.empty))
}

class Graph private (val n: Int, val adj: IndexedSeq[Set[Int]]) {
  def addEdge(u: Int, v: Int) = {
    new Graph(n, adj.updated(u, adj(u) + v).updated(v, adj(v) + u))
  }

 def connected = {
  @tailrec
  def connectedIter(q: Queue[Int], visited: Set[Int]): Boolean = {
    if (q.isEmpty) visited.size == n else {
      val (v, newq) = q.dequeue
      connectedIter(newq enqueue (adj(v) -- visited), visited ++ adj(v))
    }
  }

 connectedIter(Queue(0), Set.empty)
 }
}
```